# Two .py data importing them but it gives an error name xx is not defined

Tags: python, pyqt5

I have big problem.

So I have a main window and I have a second window. If I click the Button: `ButtonSeite` it will open my second window until now there is no problem. I have a Button on my second Window the button `calls:Ilias_Button` it will close the second button (with command `WindowButton.close()`) but if I click the `Ilias_Button` on second window it gives me an Error it calls

> NameError: name 'WindowButton' is not defined

even though I imported my second window to my main window file
please I need help here.. how can I solve this problem?

**Its my Main Window**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap
import webbrowser
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMessageBox
from WindowSec import Ui_WindowButton


class Ui_WindowMain(object):           
    def setupUi(self, WindowMain):
        WindowMain.setObjectName("WindowMain")
        WindowMain.setWindowTitle("hallooo")
        WindowMain.resize(300, 600)
        WindowMain.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(300, 600))
        WindowMain.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(300, 600))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(8)
        WindowMain.setFont(font)
        WindowMain.setContextMenuPolicy(QtCore.Qt.DefaultContextMenu)
        WindowMain.setStyleSheet("")

        #ButtonSeite
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(WindowMain)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.ButtonSeite = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.ButtonSeite.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 185, 200, 40))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.ButtonSeite.setFont(font)
        self.ButtonSeite.setStyleSheet(
        "QPushButton{background-color: grey; border-width: 2px; border-style: solid; border-color: Black}"
        "QPushButton:hover{background-color: #A4A4A4; border-width: 2px; border-style: solid; border-color: Black}"
        )
        self.ButtonSeite.setObjectName("ButtonSeite")
        self.ButtonSeite.setText("Ilias Homepage")

        #ButtonZertifikat
        self.ButtonZertifikat = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.ButtonZertifikat.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 228, 200, 40))
        font1 = QtGui.QFont()
        font1.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font1.setPointSize(14)
        font1.setBold(True)
        font1.setWeight(75)
        self.ButtonZertifikat.setFont(font1)
#        self.ButtonZertifikat.setStyleSheet("background-color: grey; border-width: 2px; border-style: solid; border-color: Black;")
        self.ButtonZertifikat.setStyleSheet(
        "QPushButton{background-color: grey; border-width: 2px; border-style: solid; border-color: Black}"
        "QPushButton:hover{background-color: #A4A4A4; border-width: 2px; border-style: solid; border-color: Black}"
        )
        self.ButtonZertifikat.setObjectName("ButtonZertifikat")
        self.ButtonZertifikat.setText("Zertifikat Speichern")

        #Menübar
        WindowMain.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(WindowMain)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 300, 19))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        self.menuMen_Text = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menuMen_Text.setObjectName("menuMen_Text")
        WindowMain.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuMen_Text.menuAction())
        self.menuMen_Text.setTitle("MenüText")



        #Label für Logo
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(WindowMain)
        self.label.setPixmap(QPixmap("Logo.png"))
        self.label.setGeometry(0,20,300,80)


        #textedit1
        self.textEdit1 = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(WindowMain)
        self.textEdit1.setGeometry(10 ,100 , 280, 100)
        self.textEdit1.setObjectName("textEdit1")
        self.textEdit1.setText(
        "ALLES NOCH UMBENNENEN NICHT VERGESSEN"
        "<p style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-size:11pt; color:#ff0000;\">asdsROOOT</span></p>\n"
        "<p style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-size:15pt; color:blue;\">HALLO</span></p>\n"
        "<p style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-size:28pt; font-style:italic; color:#ff0000;\">hallo ich heiße Cihan</span></p>\n"
        "<p style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-size:18pt; text-decoration: underline; color:#aa55ff;\">uasdasdasdasdadasdaad</span></p>\n"
        "<p style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-size:18pt; text-decoration: underline; color:#aa55ff;\">rlrlr</span></p>"
        )

        self.textEdit1.setReadOnly(True)
        self.textEdit1.setStyleSheet(
        "QTextEdit{background-color: #BDBDBD; border-width: 2px; border-style: solid; border-color: Black}"
        "QScrollBar{background-color: #BDBDBD; border-width: 2px; border-style: solid; border-color: Black}"              
        )



        self.ButtonSeite.clicked.connect(self.WindowIlias)



    def WindowIlias(self):
        self.window_Ilias = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
        self.ui = Ui_WindowButton()
        self.ui.setupUi(self.window_Ilias)
#        WindowMain.hide()
        self.window_Ilias.show()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    WindowMain = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_WindowMain()
    ui.setupUi(WindowMain)
    WindowMain.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**That is my second window**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import webbrowser


class Ui_WindowButton(object):



    def setupUi(self, WindowButton):
        WindowButton.setObjectName("WindowButton")
        WindowButton.setWindowTitle("IliasWindow")
        WindowButton.setFixedSize(300,100)
#        WindowButton.resize(436, 307)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(WindowButton)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        WindowButton.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(WindowButton)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0,0,300,100))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        WindowButton.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(WindowButton)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        WindowButton.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)


        self.info_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(WindowButton)
        self.info_label.setGeometry(10,10,200,30)
        self.info_label.setText("hallooo color und so")
        self.info_label.setStyleSheet(
        "QLabel{border-width: 2px; border-style: solid; border-color: Black}"        
        )

        self.Ilias_Button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(WindowButton)
        self.Ilias_Button.setGeometry(130,60,40,20)
        self.Ilias_Button.setText("OK")
        self.Ilias_Button.setStyleSheet(
        "QPushButton{background-color: grey; border-width: 2px; border-style: solid; border-color: Black}"
        "QPushButton:hover{background-color: #A4A4A4; border-width: 2px; border-style: solid; border-color: Black}"
        )

        self.Ilias_Button.clicked.connect(self.IliasBrowser)



    def IliasBrowser(self):

#        webbrowser.open_new_tab("https://elearning.hs-albsig.de/login.php")
        WindowButton.close()




if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    WindowButton = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_WindowButton()
    ui.setupUi(WindowButton)
    WindowButton.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: That's a variable scope issue: windowButton is local to setupUi, doesn't exist in iliasBrowser. You may want to save e reference in self

Comment: Also you should respect either pep8 or qt's naming convention, otherwise you'll soon get lost between ClassNames and variableNames or functionNames.

Comment: can you show me how can I do this please?

Comment: @Demi-Lune can you please explain shortly how can i to save e reference in self? so I can solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the 2nd file's setupUi, store a ref to WindowButton for later usage:

```
class Ui_WindowButton(object):
    def setupUi(self, WindowButton):
        self.myMasterWindowButton = WindowButton
    ...
    def IliasBrowser(self):
        self.myMasterWindowButton.close()
```

Comment: Omg, @Demi-Lune thank you very much. I have been trying to solve this problem since 12hours. Thank your very much. I have one more Question is it better to work with __init__ function or is it good how am i writing the codes?

Comment: Qt is using setupUi for (obviously) setting up the Ui. You could use `__init__` for setting up any variable that is not UI related (though I don't spot any in your code yet).